# Docker multi container multi network setup

Tags: node.js, docker, networking, docker-compose

I have read the docker docks for hours now as I'm new to it and I'm trying to create separate networks with containers communicating to each other.

(this is the requirement so please **do not propose singe network solution**)

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  client:
    container_name: client
    build: ./rest_client
    ports:
      - "5858:5858"
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - client
      - server1

  server1:
    container_name: server1
    build: ./server_instance
    ports:
      - "5841:5840"
      - "4001:4000"
    networks:
      - client
      - server1

  node1:
    container_name: node1
    build: ./node_instance
    ports:
      - "5851:5850"
      - "5001:5000"
    networks:
      - server1


networks:
  client:
    driver: bridge
  server1:
    driver: bridge
```

For the sake of simplicity I got rid of most of the servers and nodes to clarify the issue.

Having the above setup, I'm assuming that `client` is able to communicate with `server1` via either `client` or `server1` network.

When I try to send the request which looks basically like this:

```
http://client:4001/api/requestnode
```

or this :

```
http://server1:4001/api/requestnode
```

From the `client` to the `server1`

I'm getting:

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.19.0.5:4001

Which would suggest that the services do not see each other ?

When I was running tests with a single network all was fine.

What am I doing wrong ?

Help greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

--- EDIT ---
`docker run -it --rm --net container:id nicolaka/netshoot netstat -lnt`

`client` & `server1` accordintly

[image]

Also a screen shot from my local machine:

`client`:

[image]

`server1`:

[image]

```
matewilk@matewilk:~$ docker run -it --rm --net container:658d89ba410f nicolaka/netshoot nslookup server1

nslookup: can't resolve '(null)': Name does not resolve

Name:      server1
Address 1: 172.19.0.4 server1.multisite_server1



matewilk@matewilk:~$ docker run -it --rm --net container:f032cfa52c60 nicolaka/netshoot ip a

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo

       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
269: eth1@if270: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 

    link/ether 02:42:ac:12:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.18.0.2/16 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

271: eth0@if272: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 

    link/ether 02:42:ac:13:00:04 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.19.0.4/16 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For container-to-container communication, it's not necessary to publish the target port, you will be communicating directly with the target container. The application in the target container needs to be listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0, not 127.0.0.1). Assuming that's the case, you should be able to connect with:

```
http://server1:4000/api/requestnode
```

after the server has started. Note that it's possible for the client to start before the server, so you'll need to implement some form of retry or [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) like script to ensure the server has started first.

Comment: The timing it's not an issue, I can easily call all the services from my local machine. Also, I need to map ports because I have multiple instances of the same container and the requirement is that they are separate servers, so I set different port for each instance, hence mapping. Also, I'm not sure why are you mentioning `127.0.0.1`? it is not mentioned in my question at all. So the problem remains, there is no communication between containers and there is no obvious reason.

Comment: Listening on loopback is a common mistake with those new to docker. Note in my above answer you need to connect to port 4000, not port 4001, the containers don't see your published ports on the host, only the actual port inside the target container.

Comment: Same problem I'm afraid `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.2:4000`

Comment: Please update to question to include the output of `docker run -it --rm --net container:$server1_id nicolaka/netshoot netstat -lnt`, `docker run -it --rm --net container:$server1_id nicolaka/netshoot ip a`, and `docker run -it --rm --net container:$client_id nicolaka/netshoot nslookup server1`, adjusting `$server1_id` and `$client_id` to be your container id's.

Comment: Updated with the above.

Comment: @matewilk the above seems to be missing two of the requested commands.

Comment: Looking over the output, I don't see anything standing out as incorrect. The client sees the container ip to connect to, you're connecting to the container port, and the server is listening on that port on all interfaces. I see you marked the answer as accepted. If you're still having the problem, I'd uncheck this answer so someone else sees you still need help. Otherwise, be sure to post the resolution.

Comment: Thanks, this is the accepted answer, my fault I couldn't find the issue, I mixed up the container names with network names, so basically your solution works! Thanks for help.